# Given a likelihood and a set of possible parameters, determine probability a sample point was generated by a particular parameter?

Tags: probability, bayesian, likelihood

Suppose I have some probability density function $f(x | \theta)$ depending on a parameter $\theta$. I also know that $\theta$ must assume one of some finite number of values, for simplicity, let's let that number be two: $\theta_1, \theta_2$. Supposing that either $\theta$ is equally likely before I know the value of $x$, can I find an expression for the probability that $x$ was generated by a particular $\theta$ once I have $x$? i.e, I'm looking for $p(\theta = \theta_1 | x)$

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This question may require the self study tag. You didn't mention it and you are posing a Bayesian problem you need to specify a prior distribution on theta.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: the question states that the prior is uniform over $\{\theta_1,\theta_2\}$.